# How to send static files (CSS, js) with nodejs express on AWS Bitnami server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, mean-stack, bitnami

I'm developing a MEAN app using bitnami through AWS but this is the first time I've done this. I can't figure out how to send the static files in the public folder such as css and js.

I feel like I've tried every combination of configuring the apache proxy and including or not including "public" in the path but I must be missing something fundamentally. I've looked at the other Q&A on this topic but I think what I tried below uses those methods. Don't know if it has something to do with the proxy since I'm forwarding http://public-ip/test3 to the node server.

The bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file:

```
ProxyPass /test3 http://127.0.0.1:3100/
ProxyPassReverse /test3 http://127.0.0.1:3100/
```

The nodejs app.js file - tried it with an withough public in various places

```
var express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/p4.1.html");
});
app.listen(3100,'localhost',function(){
console.log("server has started");
});
```

the p4.1.html file - I've tried it with and without public in the path.

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/styles.css">
<script src="public/functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

The p4.1.html, styles.css, and functions.js are stored in the public folder. The public folder is at the same path as the app.js file.

The html page does display but I get 404 errors for the css and js: http://public-ip/public/functions.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Is this something in my code or in the proxy perhaps? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to put test3 instead of public in the url in the html file.

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test3/styles.css">
<script src="test3/functions.js"></script>
</head>
```